# Extract co-ordinates from a vector of co-ordinates and save to file

Tags: c++, opencv, vector, coordinates, extract

I have a vector which contains a list co-ordinates ...x1,y1 ; x2,y2....xn,yn

I am trying to extract each individual element which is a co-ordinate and then save them to file as a nice delineated co-ord pair which can be easily read. Or what would be nice i to save them so I can plot something in excel e.t.c (as cols of x and y values).

My original vector size is 31, and was originally constructed as

```
vector<vector<Point> > myvector( previous vector.size() );
```

Comment: @hmjd I guess "how to extract individual elements from a vector"?

Comment: yes ...in this case the individual element is a co-ordinate and i would like 'break up the list' into individual co-ord pairs. If i tried to save this vector as xml/yml it just prints a list of numbers which are my point pairs , but without proper delineation ({{1,2} , {3,4} saves as 1,2,3,4 e.t.c

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Writing to Excel File is easy in C++. You can do it as follows.

```
      #include<iostream>
      #include<fstream>
      #include<vector>

      using namespace std;

      vector<Point> myVec;

      void main()
      {
         ofstream fout("C:/output.xls");

         for(unsigned int i=0; i<myVec.Size(); i++)
         {
             int x = myVec[i].x;
             int y = myVec[i].y;

             fout<<x;      //Write value of x in first column

             fout<<"\t";   //Jump to next column

             fout<<y;      //Write value of y in next column

             fout<<endl;   //Jump to first column of next row
         }

         fout.close();
       }
```

When opening the output file with Microsoft Excel, a warning may be shown. You can just ignore it.

Comment: thanks this a great answer and is what I need to do eventually....however I do not know how to access each element pair ...for instance i call myVec.[i].front().x to access the first pair.this saves to excell perfectly ...I seem to be unable to call myVec[i].x (the error is that the class has no member 'x')...... but do not know how to scan through to the second pair and eventually to the end

Comment: what is the internal data type of vector you are using? Is it `Point` or something else?

Comment: yes I think it is a <point> but of the form  "vector<vector<Point> > myVec"

Comment: If you cout myVec[i] it will output a vector of size 1 ...and cout the contents of myVec will dump the entire list of about 50 co-oridnates ..it sees that I may have to slice the vector up somehow ....

Comment: It means its a 2 dimensional array of `Point` data type. If you are trying to store coordinates, then I would suggest that either create `vector<Point>` or `vector<vector<int>>`

Answer (score 3):

Use `std::vector<std::vector<Point>>::const_iterator` in a for loop to iterate over all elements of your coordinate list.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `at` or `[]` operator and iterate over the elements of the vector. And then save each one to a file or excel sheet as u please.

Comment: I can access the element list , with an element being a coord pair with myVec[i]...but it just dumps the entire list ....i think it consists of 0 rows...

Answer (score 0):

"Extract" an element in a vector (one possible way!):

```
std::vector<anObj> myVec;
//...fill the vector...
//get the elements:
for(int i = 0; i < myVec.length(); i++)
{
     int x = myVec.at(i).x;
     int y = myVec.at(i).y;
     //do something else
}
```

Using Excel in C++ is a bit more complex. See some [examples](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms384314%28v=vs.71%29.aspx) for managed and unmanaged ways.

Comment: calling myVec.at(i).x gives the following error "class has no member x'... possibly i would need to chop the original vector up into individual 'elements' or co-ord pairs ?

Comment: this is just an example! The "x" in this code is just hypothetical. You must use the variable from your pointer class and you must include the class to use it in this way!